# Removing HTML class from WKWebView using Swift

Tags: ios

I am trying to remove an element on WKWebView and I have seen a lot of different ways of doing it and have tried multiple different ways but it hasnt worked very well for me. So my question would be, does it work the same for both div or class?

**The HTML code below is an example code that I would like to remove.**

```
            <header class="pf-header" role="banner">
                 <div class="pf-header__top">
```

**I tried implementing it using the following code to remove the html and it didnt work**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    let header = "document.querySelector('.pf-header').style.display='none';"
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: header)

}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to debug your webview in safari with the dev tools. And then paste that JavaScript into the console and see if it has the desired effect. It’s also possible that the DOM hasn’t even loaded yet when this JavaScript is run.

Comment: Also, that is a UIWebview delegate method, not WKWebView. Has the delegate even been set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pure embarrassment but I wanted to point out I was caught a little off guard until quin pointed me that I am using WKWebView. The way to solve this is simply to use WKNavigationDelegate protocol some of the function shown below. It works right away after that.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    // Code runs when it finish loading
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    // Code runs when it start running
}
```